# Reading to hash table from file c#

Tags: c#

(In this windows form application) I'm trying to read data from a file into a hash table and populate text boxes with the data in the hash table but when I run the code I'm always thrown the exception "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: ''  Key being added: '' "

Initial code:

```
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:path/ajand.txt");

foreach (string line in fileLines)
{
    // to split the first 9 chars in the string and use them as key values                
    string[] match = Regex.Split(line, line.Substring(0,9));
    hT.Add(match[0], line);
}
```

so i tried checking for key duplicates with the following code

```
 string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:path/ajand.txt");

 foreach (string line in fileLines)
 {
     string[] match = Regex.Split(line, line.Substring(0,9));

     if(!hT.ContainsKey(match[0])) // to check duplicates
     hT.Add(match[0], line);            
 }
```

But when I run the program the corresponding text boxes are not populated with the data that "seems" to have been added to the hash table. 
Please any ideas what the problem is.

Comment: Your Regex.Split line is wrong. You need to put a regular expression in there. What do you want to split on?

Comment: Could you post the code for populating your text boxes?

Comment: A short sample of what your ajand.txt file looks like would help I think.

Comment: @FrancisGagnon I'm trying to split numbers(0-9) and "/\" from characters(string of words)

Comment: Your Regex definitely needs work... based on the comment you are just grabbing the first 9 characters of a string and storing it based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could use a function like this one:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> LoadActivityLookup(string filePath) {
    const int KEY_LENGTH = 10;
    var newLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath)) {
        if (line.Length < KEY_LENGTH) continue;
        string key = line.Substring(0, KEY_LENGTH);
        if (!newLookup.ContainsKey(key)) {
            string value = line.Substring(KEY_LENGTH);
            newLookup.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
    return newLookup;
}
```

Dictionaries are great for repeatedly looking up keys in a large set of keys. But if you only need to hold a bunch of key/value pairs in a collection so that you can later iterate through them, I would go with a List<> instead.

Here is a version of the above function which uses a StreamReader instead of loading the complete file in a string array.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> LoadActivityLookup(string filePath) {
    const int KEY_LENGTH = 10;
    var newLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(filePath)) {
        string line = rdr.ReadLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.Length < KEY_LENGTH) {
                line = rdr.ReadLine();
                continue;
            } 
            string key = line.Substring(0, KEY_LENGTH);
            if (!newLookup.ContainsKey(key)) {
                string value = line.Substring(KEY_LENGTH);
                newLookup.Add(key, value);
            }
            line = rdr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    return newLookup;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Francis i tried using StreamReader as in the code above and it works fine. I had to do some modifications though but thanks for the idea.

Comment: @dhani - Don't forget to add a green check next to your favorite answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static Hashtable HashtableFromFile(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                return (Hashtable)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return new Hashtable(); 
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove duplicates, you can simply use the index to add/update to the hashtable:

```
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:path/ajand.txt");

foreach (string line in fileLines)
{
    // to split the first 10 chars in the string and use them as key values                
    string key = line.Length > 10 ? line.Substring(0,10) : line;
    hT[key] = line;
}
```

Comment: @FrancisGagnon
the file contents are like so:
**10/07/2012 Will go to swimming at 10.30**  
so i'm trying to split the date from the activity and use the date as the and the other part as value, load them into the hash table and display in the text boxes

Comment: this is the code for populating the text boxes @J Torres. Same code applies to the other text boxes.
`if (textBox1.Text.Length != 0)// if text box is empty
            {
                if (hT.ContainsKey(label1.Text) == false) // if this HT location contains no data
                    hT.Add(label1.Text, textBox1.Text);// add data
                else
                    hT[label1.Text] = textBox1.Text; // if it contains data modify it..
                textBox1.Clear();
            }`

Comment: it's hard to read code in a comment (this really should go into the question), but it looks like your code adds whatever is in a text box, then clears it.  I don't see anything that would actually populate a text box as you reference.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. It assumes that the separator between the date and the rest of the line is a space.
It will try to parse the date into a DateTime object and use it as a key. It will use the rest of the line as the value. The fact that the indexer is used to put values into the dictionary eliminates duplicate key problems, but at the same time it will overwrite values if you have entries that have the same date. In this case only the last entry with that date will be saved into the dictionary.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\path\ajand.txt");

foreach (var line in lines) {
    var index = line.Trim().IndexOf(" ");
    if (index == -1) {
        continue;
    }

    DateTime key;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(line.Substring(0, index), out key)) {
        hT[key] = line.Substring(index);
    }
}
```